# emberjs + rails, capture keypress event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, keypress, enter

I test the js script in the normal html file

```js
$(document).ready ->
  $("#subject").keyup (event) ->
    alert "wll"
```

it works.

but when I use it in emberjs + rails project.
it does not work

what's up with that?

Answer (score 1):

There is one rule: all events you should put to your `views` (http://emberjs.com/guides/views/).

There you have list of all events:

```
EVENT NAMES
Possible events names for any of the responding approaches described above are:

Touch events:

touchStart
touchMove
touchEnd
touchCancel
Keyboard events

keyDown
keyUp
keyPress
Mouse events

mouseDown
mouseUp
contextMenu
click
doubleClick
mouseMove
focusIn
focusOut
mouseEnter
mouseLeave
Form events:

submit
change
focusIn
focusOut
input
HTML5 drag and drop events:

dragStart
drag
dragEnter
dragLeave
drop
dragEnd
```

This is simple example how you can use this:

#### HTML

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <div class='box'>Test</div>
</script>
```

#### JS

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    // This is only for set the focus on our view.
    didInsertElement: function() {
      return this.$().attr({ tabindex: 1 }), this.$().focus();
    },
    keyPress: function(event) {
        console.log("KeyCode: " + event.keyCode);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using a view you can simply do this

```
AView = Ember.View.extend({
   keyUp: function(event){
       alert('wll');
   }
});
```